# Is there a function in SQL to determine the area of of a rectangle that is not being impacted by other intersecting rectangles?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, intersection, area

I am trying to determine the space for each of the rectangles (red, blue, orange, etc) where there is no other rectangles intersecting. The points of each rectangle is known. The number of rectangles and the number of rectangles that are intersecting will change depending on the dataset being run so are not limited to 5.

eg:

With this mock up
[Intersecting Rectangles Start Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E4Od.png).

I would expect the blue rectangle to return that the total area was being intersected. While the Pink Rectangle would show that a portion is still ok. eg. [Area that are not intersected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9MYC.png)

| Rectangle | Total Area | Area Of Intersection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 1000cm2 | 300cm2 |
| Orange | 900cm2 | 400cm2 |
| Blue | 700cm2 | 700cm2 |
| Pink | 200cm2 | 180cm2 |
| Green | 900cm2 | 420cm2 |

I was using the inclusion exclusion principle in earlier runs when it was just 2 intersecting rectangles but due to their being an unknown number of intersecting rectangles I don't think it is feasible especially when the intersecting rectangles could also be overlapping like the pink rectangle.

I am also not stuck to doing this within SQL but I'm not familiar with any other languages at this point.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using as the solution is almost certainly going to be product specific. You are also highly unlikely to be able to do this is pure SQL, you’d need to use whatever programming language your DBMS supports and loop through each rectangle and calculate the overlap(or not) with all the other rectangles

Comment: Sounds like a recursion problem or at least a simple loop. For each pair of rectangles, determine the overlaps. Then recurse into the overlap of the overlap, etc. until there are no more.

Comment: I just played around with the idea here. It a "manual" recursion via CTEs and I think it's on the right track. https://dbfiddle.uk/xc-Wimkx